# How to calculate with multiple value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to dividing field "budget" with multiple value

Look like "SELECT fName, (budget/ 2,3,4) FROM Table"

```
fName    budget
---------------
A        100      >>divide with 2
B        100      >>divide with 4
C        100      >>divide with 6
```

The result is

```
 fName    budget
    ---------------
    A        50     
    B        25
    C        16.67
```

Comment: What's your expected output? `SELECT fName, (budget/2/4/6) FROM table` ?

Comment: Need more info here for a proper answer.

Comment: Where `2, 4, 6` came from?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Pls describe what you would like to achive in more detailed manner.

Comment: Sorry for unclear answer.
The result is 
A 50
B 25
C 16.67

Comment: post the complete requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fname,CASE WHEN fname ='A' THEN budget/2
                  WHEN fname ='B' THEN budget/4
                  WHEN fname ='C' THEN budget/6
             END
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it's very unclear what you're asking, I guess you may need something like this:

create temporary table and put your desired values in it. then make a `cross join` to your main table:

```
SELECT 
      fName
    , Table.budget / tempTable.ColumnName
FROM 
     Table CROSS JOIN tempTable
```